# PHP SDK for using ec2 instance as owner

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

There are several ways to use an ec2 instance as owner. like ssh and puTTY. could it be done from php sdk, too?

Comment: how are you going to run PHP without having Apache running on the server?

Comment: In order to even process the request, PHP would have to be running. How would you install PHP, with a PHP request?...

Comment: by PHP, I meant AWS SDK for PHP installed on your local computer

Comment: Your question is still not clear. You can use AWS SDK from php as you already know. that sdk can be used either from command line or even from a web server.

Comment: There are several ways to use an ec2 instance as owner. like ssh and puTTY. could it be done from php sdk, too?